# Hopper to trigger say command for each item inserted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I have a hopper sorting system that is working but the issue is that I want it to trigger a command block per item. I have the command blocks setup and working but it only does it once per stack of items, I want it to do it for each one. How would I do this?[image: <code>Image One</code>] [image: Image Two] [image: Image Three]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the transfer speed of the entry hopper for each segment (just below the top row of hoppers) so that the comparator has enough time to reduce in strength before the next item passes through. Keep in mind that this will slow down the sorting mechanism by at least 4 game ticks (2 redstone ticks). Image example:

[image: Hopper transfer speed]

The command would target the hopper circled in yellow, adjusting coordinates as needed:

```
/blockdata ~1 ~4 ~ {TransferCooldown:4}
```

Comment: When I place the new command block it doesn't fire the one under the chest. It also removes the 22 items in the hopper above the one connected to the chest. It leaves only 9 items.

Comment: Nevermind, this was being caused by the command block being empty causing it to not output a signal. Thank you!

Comment: I just ran into an issue. This isn't working if there is more than one type of input. For example in my photo's there are 7 different chests for 7 different items. adding another hopper doesn't allow it to work because it can only hit the one and not get sorted by the others. Is there a way to fix this?